# Jquery Dynamic Div Height

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html

```
$('#menu-window-inner').css(
    {'height':
        ( 
            ($('#menu-window').height()) - 
            ($('#menu-window-title').height()) -
            ($('#menu-window-footer').height()) 
        )
    }
);
```

So I'm trying to use the code above to set the height of "menu-window-inner". It works when I use the equation X=A-B, but not when I use X=A-B-C. Basically it only works when subtracting the height of one div, not two.

Anyone know the correct fix? Having read over the code and css it all looks correct to me so I'm bamboozled.

Comment: Can you please give us more info like: what is your html? what have you tried? why doesn't it "work" with two subtractions, etc?

Comment: What is the result of the subtraction of the three heights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use outerHeight() and height() functions of jQuery here:

```
$('#menu-window-inner').height(
    $('#menu-window').outerHeight() - 
    $('#menu-window-title').outerHeight() - 
    $('#menu-window-footer').outerHeight()
);
```

and your code is not working because wou need to append "px" at the end of the value when using CSS height property.

Comment: But he wrote it works fine for him with two elements...? _" It works when I use the equation X=A-B, but not when I use X=A-B-C. Basically it only works when subtracting the height of one div, not two."_

Comment: The "px" is not necessary in jquery's `.css()`

Comment: I said what I know. If you write `width:355;` in your css file hardcoded, it doesn't work. But if you write `width:355px` it works. There isn't anything wrong in my answer.

Comment: it does work fine with 2 elements but it always ignored the third. Either way, cheers tpaksu your answer worked perfectly. Much appreciated.

Comment: @tpaksu Saying that it doesn't work of the "px" makes your answer technically wrong. But I haven't downvoted or anything like that. Just pointing it out.

Comment: Ok @d_inevitable I have no grudge or anything. Just making my point. Thanks.